# Genymotion in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, genymotion

How to import `genymotion` in `Qt Creator`? I want to run my mobile applications with `Genymotion`.

I searched on internet but I could find for Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no direct support for Genymotion in Qt Creator. You can certainly add the apk install step in your project's deploy steps. Genymotion's [gm-tool](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/gm-tool) command line utility can be easily invoked from Qt Creator.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know that. How can I add that commands with gmtool in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2):

In case you (or somebody else) are still interested, in Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB and set path to Android SDK that you use in Qt Creator:

[image]

Then Qt Creator should recognize the genymotion emulator.